# is it possible to have multiple country shapes(from default) in shape map visual?

Tags: powerbi

Currently,i am using shape map visual to represent country & respective states, but for three countries i have to use three visuals. i have tried using add map option but it requires to select shape(map) from system. is there a way to have multiple countries in one visual from existing map options?

Answer (score 0):

For the shape map visual, you import your on file in the topoJSON format, you can't at this time add more that one file to the visual.

However you can get individual topoJSON files for the countries and then merge them together into one file, that then can be displayed in one visual. There is a [SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33390422/how-can-i-merge-multiple-topojson-files-into-single-topojson-file) that outlines how to do this

Hope that helps